# jQuery only working in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I am new to jQuery - I am trying to use it to hide an element once a user scrolls past a certain point on the page. It seems to work in Chrome but not in Firefox or IE? What am I doing wrong!?

Code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/25az3pL2/6/

```
window.onscroll = function (event) {
var mydivpos = document.getElementById("move_to").offsetTop;
var scrollPos = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop;

if(scrollPos >= mydivpos)
document.getElementById("mobile_form_prompt").className = "hidden";
else
document.getElementById("mobile_form_prompt").className = "";
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the code

Comment: what you are trying? can you paste it here?

Comment: Sorry - code in place now

Answer (score 0):

you should try some thing like this.

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){   
    var mydivpos = $("#move_to").offsetTop;
    var scrollPos = $("body")[0].scrollTop;
    if( scrollPos >= mydivpos ) {
        $("#mobile_form_prompt").attr('class') = 'hidden';
    else
        $("mobile_form_prompt").attr('class') = "";
    }
  });
});
```